# IPython engines returning different results

Tags: python, numpy, ipython, ipython-parallel

Hopefully someone can enlighten me without me having to post a lot of confusing code.

I am using IPython.parallel to process neural networks.  In an attempt to find a bug I decided to send the same network out to each client with the same input data.  I would expect to have each client return the same answer, which most of the time, it does.  However sometimes I will get vastly different results from each client.

here's just a sample of running the code 5 different times.  Each time the code is run a new network is built and so I would expect a different solution between runs, however, each run I am sending out the same network to each client...

I am using apply_async to send out the process to the different clients (all of which are on a single local machine.)

no random numbers are being generated during the processing and the only math functions I am using are the built in `pow()` and `numpy.tanh()`.

any ideas on the best way to track down what's going on?

```
%> ./ld_cluster.py
Available workers:  5
importing sys on engine(s)
0 ) b0ca598b-8cc8-4de7-8e6e-f62c1e6eba58 :: 2.020202
0 ) b0ca598b-8cc8-4de7-8e6e-f62c1e6eba58 :: 2.020202
0 ) b0ca598b-8cc8-4de7-8e6e-f62c1e6eba58 :: 2.020202
0 ) b0ca598b-8cc8-4de7-8e6e-f62c1e6eba58 :: 2.020202
0 ) b0ca598b-8cc8-4de7-8e6e-f62c1e6eba58 :: 2.020202
%> ./ld_cluster.py
Available workers:  5
importing sys on engine(s)
0 ) ff0ac798-3eb9-43cd-940a-6bc77447a3b4 :: 1.846979
0 ) ff0ac798-3eb9-43cd-940a-6bc77447a3b4 :: 1.846979
0 ) ff0ac798-3eb9-43cd-940a-6bc77447a3b4 :: 1.846979
0 ) ff0ac798-3eb9-43cd-940a-6bc77447a3b4 :: 1.846979
0 ) ff0ac798-3eb9-43cd-940a-6bc77447a3b4 :: 1.846979
%> ./ld_cluster.py
Available workers:  5
importing sys on engine(s)
0 ) f679d9c3-9e00-4b32-84b7-72fcf9fb5da0 :: 2.021491
0 ) f679d9c3-9e00-4b32-84b7-72fcf9fb5da0 :: 2.021491
0 ) f679d9c3-9e00-4b32-84b7-72fcf9fb5da0 :: 2.021491
0 ) f679d9c3-9e00-4b32-84b7-72fcf9fb5da0 :: 2.021491
0 ) f679d9c3-9e00-4b32-84b7-72fcf9fb5da0 :: 2.021491
%> ./ld_cluster.py
Available workers:  5
importing sys on engine(s)
0 ) f28617ef-72e7-4de3-a0a7-a98057efaa2e :: 1.979795
0 ) f28617ef-72e7-4de3-a0a7-a98057efaa2e :: 1.979795
0 ) f28617ef-72e7-4de3-a0a7-a98057efaa2e :: 1.979795
0 ) f28617ef-72e7-4de3-a0a7-a98057efaa2e :: 1.979795
0 ) f28617ef-72e7-4de3-a0a7-a98057efaa2e :: 1.979795
%> ./ld_cluster.py
Available workers:  5
importing sys on engine(s)
0 ) dd635626-4881-4470-909f-6a2fbe73b06d :: 2.020196
0 ) dd635626-4881-4470-909f-6a2fbe73b06d :: 1.991076
0 ) dd635626-4881-4470-909f-6a2fbe73b06d :: 1.952310
0 ) dd635626-4881-4470-909f-6a2fbe73b06d :: 1.887462
0 ) dd635626-4881-4470-909f-6a2fbe73b06d :: 2.019929
```

Comment: How about logging the value of internal variables, and compare them when the results are different.

Comment: It could be that some global or static variables do not get reinitialized properly - restart the cluster to ensure you have identical starting conditions.

Comment: Are the workers always fed exactly the same data in exactly the same order? Not sure exactly what your workers do here, but maybe execution order could be a problem?

Comment: I'm new to iPython and can't seem to figure out the correct method for logging/debuging code that is running on the engines.  How do I get a look at the state of the variables that are running on the engines?

Answer (score 0):

Thought I should show the answer (if it can be called that) here as well...

Please see [THIS THREAD.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21268990/debug-ipython-parallel-engines-in-cluster/21271896#21271896)